# Azure mediaserver keeps job in processing

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am using mediaserver to encode video jobs however I have 2 jobs which is being kept in processing, which is kind of annoying as they block the following encoding jobs. Any Ideas to why this is happeningand how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: the number of jobs you can do at the same time is equal to the number of encoding units you have. How many do you have configured?

Comment: Yes I know, We used 5 units at the time, but the issue was that the jobs never ended. However I can see today that the jobs have ended with encoding errors. It took 1.5 hours to end instead of the usual 2 minutes. I must take a look to see if its possible to put a max time to use on the encoding job.